# Is there a tableau REST API can get me a list of filters on a given dashboard?

Tags: tableau-api

I’m trying to find a way to get the filter’s names from dashboard. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not REST but the metadata api would have that. It's GraphQL. https://help.tableau.com/current/api/metadata_api/en-us/index.html

Answer (score 0):

By using tableau extension or tableau api will be able to get filter names and values from tableau dashboard

worksheet.getFiltersAsync()

Refer this: https://github.com/tableau/extensions-api/blob/main/Samples/Filtering/filtering.js